# Kill game, how does it change your starting hand value?

Tags: poker-strategy, kill

Generally when a pot is killed tight games get tighter, and loose games get looser, I really do not know what people are thinking in kill pots. 
Does position become more important? Should you play more hands, less hands?

Comment: *"...please disqualify yourself from answering"*.  Please stop giving orders and being rude to other users.  In another comment you asked an user to *"think"* and *"please delete your question"*.  Now you're asking others to *"please disqualify yourself from answering"*.  I'm sorry but that is extremely rude and this is **not** how StackExchange works. Nobody would be losing anything if you were to begin to show some courtesy in your questions / comments / meta posts.

Comment: Perhaps there is no need for those distinctions Jon, as the voting system would filter out poor answers anyway.

Comment: So are there any requests for clarifications?

Comment: Probably, just add a short link/explanation of what a kill game is.

Comment: I added a tag, with definition and links to more info.

Comment: This question is really non-specific and IMO not good for this format.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer That is simply an incorrect opinion. While the question may seem general, the particular range of answers are not.

Comment: It's a lot of questions in one, which forks it into lots of directions. I think each of those things is a useful topic, though together it seems like it could spider out of control. When you're asking what people are thinking, I'm not sure you can really distill it down to a good Q & A. I'm definitely not sold on poker in general being a good topic for the stack exchange format since poker is inherently more discussiony than Q & A, but that's a topic for meta.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your posts are generally interesting, informative, and thought provoking, and I have taken what you've written on some topics and used it as a starting point to waste an enjoyable few hours on the interwebs, but I just think this question is a little too open ended. It basically translates to "WTH do I do in a kill pot?" and -- while potentially interesting and important -- doesn't fit in the Q & A format.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer let it ride for awhile, then if it proves to inane no replies vote to close and I will more likely then not vote to close with you or just delete it myself. I am not sold either that SE is a good place for poker. I am wondering if they will tolerate a little more "Poker Style" or just decide they are better off sticking with a terse application of their original vision at SE. I would rather see you all push the envelope then keep it the way it is. Hey that sums up all my BS here.

Answer (score 1):

My answers are predicate on a Limit game. I've never seen a kill on anything but a Limit game.

- Does position become more important?

The forced action gets expensive quickly, so being behind the kill is a huge advantage, but otherwise, the "rules" of position are pretty much the same as normal. E.g. play weak holdings less often in early position.

When you have the kill, and you are better than your opponents, defend it with your life. If you have the kill, and are worse than your opponents, let it go.  The game simply plays bigger.

- Should you play more hands, less hands?

I tend to play more kill hands because the bets feel bigger, and opponents are scared of the bet sizing.  You can induce a lot of poor play just being aggressive, when simple aggression doesn't typically work in a Limit game.  Many players "won't pay more than $X" on a draw in Limit, regardless of the correctness of that call.

Answer (score -1):

I do not profess to be an expert with kill pots or straddles. But, my understanding is that it should *not* change your starting hands, but it should change your opening raise size. There's enough money committed to the pot that you should take into account your X sizing as well as ALL of the pot.

It's generally a mistake to raise 3X of the kill if there's other limpers in there. You should remember to calculate the pot as a function of *all* limpers and then 3X raise the *pot* (or whatever other X you think makes sense).

Comment: While I suppose it may be done in no limit, kill games are typically played in limit games. Sometimes in hold'em, much more often in Omaha 8 or better.

Comment: I've never seen a kill in anything but a Limit structure.